# J maximal of a direct sum.

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

1. Let be $M$ a semi simple A-module and $f$ an homomorphism from $N$ to $M$. Then the Jacobson radical is contained in $Kerf$.

I’m studying semi simple algebras and im stuck with the the demonstration of
the jacobson radical of $F[G]$.

So i wanna show that 1. My try:

We have $N/Kerf \cong M $ and then $N/Kerf$ is semisimple. So is a direct sum of two simple modules, $N/Kerf = N_1/Kerf \text{ }\oplus N_2/Kerf$. Then $Kerf$ is maximal of both $N_1$ and $N_2$. Is then maximal of $N_1 \oplus N_2 = N$?

Comment: By $Kerf$, do you mean $\text{Ker}(f)$? If so, please see the [MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Since $M$ is semisimple, it is a direct sum $\bigoplus_i S_i$ of simple modules.
Thus, a morphism $f \colon N \to M$ is determined by its components $f_i \colon N \to S_i$. Moreover,
$$
\ker f = \textstyle \bigcap_i \ker f_i.
$$
Now use the following characterization of the Jacobson radical:

*The Jacobson radical of a module $L$ is the intersection $\bigcap_g \ker g$, where $g$ runs over all morphisms from $L$ to a simple module*.